# CSS: indenting elements between x and y

Tags: css, parent-child

Take a look at this JS Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/LJLTX/3/

What I want to do is indent the content in every row between the 2nd row and last row.  In this case, it would be the 3rd, 4th and 5th rows.

How can I accomplish this in CSS?

Comment: Why are you marking this up in a table?

Comment: You should try using classes and hierarchy instead of numbers to identify your elements.

Comment: What browsers are you trying to support? There are some pretty crazy pseudo-selectors you can use, but not everyone has those yet.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is correct fiddle for that: http://jsfiddle.net/DmcEB/2/

Comment: So you just change `slice(1)` to `slice(1,-1)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with JQuery:

```
$('.geniusPicks tr>td').slice(1,5).addClass('indent')
```

I added the class indent:

http://jsfiddle.net/DmcEB/1/

Comment: text-indent will be better than padding.

Answer (score 0):

If you can rely on the visitor having a modern browser, you can use:

```
td {
    padding-left: 20px;     // or whatever distance you need
}
tr:nth-child(2) td,
tr:last-child td {
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

But that does not work in older versions of IE (I´m not even sure about IE8) so to address that you could give the first real row (not the header row) and the last row of the table a class and use:

```
td {
    padding-left: 20px;     // or whatever distance you need
}
.first_real_row_class td,
.last_row_class td {
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Again: use text-indent instead of padding.

Comment: @methyl That depends; if the text can span more lines and you want it all to indent, you need something like padding. But in the end that´s up to the OP, I am just trying to illustrate the selectors.